# How to Select latest record for a customer from a table with column value from the first row

Tags: mysql, sql

I have scenario like below

Sign up promo code

The sign up promo code, if applicable, is what the member used to create their membership.
Our system currently creates a new line for a member each time they make a change, for example upgrading/downgrading their plan.
The promo code currently doesn't get carried over and we want to make sure we're capturing this to properly analyze member acquisition.

EX:
Membership_id : 1

Membership_id: 1 first signing in with promo code : New10

second upgrading to higher version without promocode

third upgrading to another higher version without promocode

so we have 3 lines in database in first line we have promocode : New10 but other 2 lines don't have promocode .

As per below example latest record for membership id 1 is created on 2022-09-25, I want to select that latest record with promocode New10. Can you please suggest the MySQL logic for this ?

For example

```
Id        Membership_id     promocode createdtime             
1               1            New10    2022-08-01
2               1                     2022-09-14
3               1                     2022-09-25
```

Here , I want to select latest record for each membership id but want to select code column from first record when its created like below

expected output:

```
ID  Membership_id   promocode   createdtime
3       1   new10   25-09-2022
```

Comment: Surely you don't use duplicate ID's? Thats asking for trouble.

Comment: Its for MySQL @DaleK

Comment: Then why did you tag other database engines? Every product is different...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the simple solution.

```
select   max(id)          as id
        ,Membership_id   
        ,max(promocode)   as promocode
        ,max(createdtime) as createdtime
from     t
group by Membership_id
```

| id | Membership_id | promocode | createdtime |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 1 | New10 | 2022-09-25 |

Here's a solution that will give you the first `promocode` in case a customer got more than one.

```
select   id
        ,Membership_id       
        ,first_promocode as promocode
        ,createdtime
from     (
         select  *
                ,max(case when grp = 1 then promocode end) over(partition by Membership_id order by createdtime) as first_promocode
         from    (
                 select  *
                         ,count(case when promocode is not null then 1 end) over(partition by Membership_id order by createdtime) as grp
                         ,rank() over(partition by Membership_id order by createdtime desc) as rnk
                  from    t
                 ) t
         ) t
where    rnk = 1
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/uXQ2SB1c)

Comment: Thank you so much for you reply @DannySlor

I have same kind of scenario which should give me the created time line promocode as expected output. (We have multiple promocode in column)

INSERT INTO t
  (Id, Membership_id, promocode, createdtime)
VALUES
  ('1', '1', 'New10', '2022-08-01'),
  ('2', '1', 'NEW20', '2022-09-14'),
  ('3', '1', null, '2022-09-25');

Comment: @Saranya My second query will give you the last promocode used. so `NEW20` in that case.

Comment: I just need the first promo code NEW10 itself based on createdtime

Comment: @Saranya so in your scenario you want it to present 'NEW10'?

Comment: Yes @danny you are correct ... in all the 3 lines i need the 1st created line promocode as my output

Comment: Thank you so much @Danny ... Will check on this and let you know ....

Comment: thank you so much @DannySlor ,... your Query is absolutely correct .. Timely Help .. Once again Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

Try it. It should work.

```
SELECT max(Id) as ID, 
Membership_id, 
(SELECT promocode from [table_name] group by Membership_id having min(Id)) as promocode, 
createdtime 
FROM [table_name] 
group by Membership_id;
```

Answer (score 1):

So, this is very simple, you can just group by membership_id and then, select the max of all columns in the group,

**It will give you the latest id(because that's maximum)
also will give you the promocode (because that's maximum as all other fields are NULL having ASCII value 0)**

also will give you the latest date.

AND, then just select the membership_id as well as you are grouping based on it, so it's easy

```
select max(id),membership_id,max(promocode),max(createdtime) from tbl group by membership_id;
```

Here is a fiddle for it:-
https://dbfiddle.uk/qYLwn9Oz

Click it and see for yourself.. Nice question though